# I am stumbling on getting my substring to show a certain outcome

Tags: javascript, function, return, conditional-statements

I am stumbling across this code about typeofs and if/else statements

I get baffled on getting my substring to show a certain outcome. It is returning strings but not the other one ("not strings"):

```
/*
Follow the instructions - Create a function called "isString" that takes 3 arguments (x1, x2, x3)
- check if each argument is a string using typeof.
- If each argument is a string, return "strings"
- If each argument is NOT a string, return "not strings"

*/

//Write your code here
////////////////////////////////////////

function isString(a, b, c) {
  if (typeof isString === 'a','b','c') {
    return "strings";
  }
  else if (typeof isString !== 'a', 'b', 'c') {
    return "not strings";
  }
  isString(x1, x2, x3);
}

////////////////////////////////////////

//open the browser console to check results
console.log('results: ', isString('a', 'b', 'c'));

//don't change this line
if (typeof module !== 'undefined') {
  module.exports = isString;
}
```

Comment: I think the problem is that you are comparing a function to a character.

Comment: Start by reading the [typeof docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) and look at the possible return values in *Result* column. Then check each of the arguments. You will also want to learn about the `&&` operator. Right now you are way off base and it;s just not right for us to do the assignment for you. That is not what SO is about.

Comment: Thanks @charlietfl it's definitely confusing me - hopefully someone can answer on the thread

Comment: @MohamedAli not sure what you mean by that? I am new to JavaScript - what is a character

Comment: Break it down into smaller steps. Try just evaluating one argument and then work your way up. Then research how to combine multiple conditions in an `if()`. You can't eat an elephant all in one bite

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
function isString(a, b, c) {
  const allStrings = [...arguments].every(a => typeof a === 'string');
  return allStrings ? 'all strings' : 'not all strings';
}
console.log(isString('a', 'b', 'c'))
console.log(isString('a', 'b', 8))
```

Comment: Someone helped me find the answer with this:

Comment: Yours is doing exactly what mine is doing, just in a different way and with more lines.

Comment: It’s also redundant with having to repeat the same typeof multiple times. That’s why I thought .every() was preferable.

Comment: Oh thank you @wesleyAC - I am beginner in JS so I don't understand your code as much

Answer (score 0):

```
function isString(a, b, c) {
if (typeof a === 'string' && typeof b === 'string' && typeof c === 'string') {
return 'strings'
} else {
return 'not strings';
}
}
```

this is what they corrected for me ^

Answer (score -1):

Iterate through the arguments and check the type:

```js
function isString(a, b, c) {
  var valid = true;
  [...arguments].forEach(e => valid = typeof e != "string" ? false : true);
  return valid ? "strings" : "not strings";
}
console.log(isString('a', 'b', 'c'))
```

Comment: I honestly think that throwing spread operator on `arguments` and using ternaries and arrow functions is going to make this more confusing to a beginner than helping. A bit like a child learning to walk then expect them to run track & field 200 yard hurdles immediately

Comment: @undefinedmyself what's not working? What did you try it on that didn't work?